# Synchronizing with WinSCP fails for FTP files with a leading space

Tags: ftp, filenames, winscp, filezilla

I'm using WinSCP to synchronize a remote FTP directory to a local one, some files have leading space in their names, those files are not found for WinSCP with error

> Error transferring file '/xml/ file.mask.some.file.xml.gz'
>   Copying files from remote side failed.
>   File not found

The command I'm using is:

```
C:\tools\winscp.com /command ^
    "option batch on" ^
    "option confirm off" ^
    "open ftp://user:password@server -certificate=""" ^
    "synchronize local ""D:\FTP\Data\PM"" ""/xml/"" -filemask=*file.mask.*.xml.gz>200D;" ^
    "exit"
```

How can I ignore this leading space when getting these files?

Comment: What do you mean by *"ignoring this leading space"*? What exactly do you want to do with those files?

Comment: I want to download them to the local location, I mean how to fix this error so that '/xml/ fileNameWithLeadingSpace.xml.gz' is downloaded successfully

Comment: What version of WinSCP are you using?

Comment: Winscp version 5.9.1

Comment: Please post a log file showing the problem (ideally, use the latest version of WinSCP).

Comment: sorry for the question, but where do I get the log from? I mean I'm running the command in cmd and I posted the error I'm getting, anyway I edited the post please find the entire message I'm getting

Comment: Add `/log=C:\some\path\winscp.log` to your WinSCP command-line.

Comment: I added almost the entire log message

Comment: Sorry, but the log is formatted in a way that is useless for purposes of your problem + Anyway, can you download those files using any FTP client (even GUI one)?

Comment: yes using winscp GUI it downloads normally, sorry for the formatting I wish I could attach the log file

Comment: So paste the log to https://pastebin.com/ + Paste separatelly also GUI log showing download of the same file.

Comment: here is the link https://pastebin.com/yHkjMj9d

Comment: And the GUI log?

Comment: actually it seems that it's failing from GUI also, please check the picture attached

Comment: OK, so again: Can you download those files using any FTP client?

Comment: I tried FileZilla GUI and it also didn't work, but weirdly enough the same scenario with Winscp is working on another server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a server-side problem.

You are using FileZilla FTP server 0.9.41 beta (2012-02-26). That version did not allow working with files with leading/trailing whitespaces. This was [fixed in 0.9.43 (2014-01-02)](https://filezilla-project.org/versions.php?type=server).

Try updating your FileZilla FTP server to the latest version. I have no problem downloading a file with a leading space when using version 0.9.60.2.

---

You also need to have a recent version of WinSCP (5.8 and later), as old versions [did not allow working with files with leading spaces](https://winscp.net/tracker/26) either.